# the rpc server is unavailable ssis

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssms

I recently installed my Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio(SSMS).

I havem my sql express installed.

Why am I getting this error when I try to login using integreated services method.Tried almost everything from google search(Turned Firewall off,edited policies).

On thing I didn't got was MsDtsSrv.exe which had to be added to firewall exeptions.

I have been trying this since last few days. Please help.
**Error Message**
[image]

**Anything Wrong here?**
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully this is resolved by now, but here's for posterity.

This is very likely just a firewall issue (it was for me).

Remote to your server and open up Windows Firewall; you need to allow `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\xxx\DTS\Binn\MsDtsSrvr.exe` through the firewall, and then you need to create a new rule to open up TCP port 135.

Comment: Hello @Mat's Mug I dont even remember clearly, what the issue was. I was trying to create a .NET SOAP webservice but now I have moved to android development field. Anyway, thanks for your reply. I will upvote for your good spirit.